# List VBA functions in module in protected project

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get the names of all the functions in a given module in a VBA project so I can then run them all by calling them by name. I have been able to achieve this by following the info [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx).

However, this workbook is to be distributed for use and I need to password protect the VBA code. When the VBA project is password protected, I get "Run-time error '50289': Can't perform operation since the project is protected"

I have isolated the following line of code as the cause for the error:

```
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
```

Is there any other way to list all the functions in a module or run all the functions in a module to which I am passing inputs and getting outputs?

Comment: I'm not quite following you here. You have a workbook that is to be distributed, and you will password-protect the workbook's VBA project for distribution. Fine. But do you not have access now to the unlocked project? Once it goes into production the project should not be changed again. So whatever's there now will be what's there later.

Comment: This sounds like a design issue more than anything else.  If you need to run all of the functions "by calling them by name", that indicates a problem. It isn't like the function names are going to change - just put them in a delimited constant string and `Split` it.

Comment: There is about 80 functions, and functions will be added and removed in future versions of this workbook. The idea was that in future versions, all that needs to be done is delete or add the relevant functions and then changes aren't needed elsewhere (e.g. changes to a string/list that contains all the function names). Having a list or string with the function names or calling all the functions one after another was something I had thought of as a last resort but wanted to avoid.